# How can I multiply a tensor with an unknown dimension to a tensorflow variable?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm working in Keras (Tensorflow 2). I'd like to multiply each element of a tensor with its own trainable weight. Let's say that my input tensor is 1D, with 10 elements; so I try to define the input as a Keras input tensor, the weights as a tf.Variable, and I try to use the Keras Multiply layer, thus:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10), name='inputs')
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10]), name='weights')
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([inputs, weights])
```

Now when I inspect the dimensions they are:

```
inputs: shape=(None, 10)
weights: shape=(10,)
outputs: shape=(10, 10)
```

The input dimension has a None dimension, for the batch size, which is what I expect and want. However I expected outputs to have shape=(None, 10). Instead, the initial dimension for the batch size seems to have taken a fixed size of 10. How should I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to broadcast weights along dimenstion 0. The shape of the dimension you want to fix must be constant.

That is, weights must have the shape `(1, 10)`, not `(10,)`.

This can be done using:

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 10]), name='weights')
```

or

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10]), name='weights')
...
weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, axis=0)
```